# Create my own tags?

Tags: actionscript-3, tags, substring

Let's say i have a like a chat or forum, and whenever someone sends/posts a message with tags for ex: <'video> A youtube link <'/video>  i want to appear as a video when i can play it (like http://prntscr.com/1r2o4k) ...
So does anyone know a method i can do this? I can't realise how to do it -.-

I already know how to make the video appear like that, all I need to realise is how to make the tags method work, sth like this

```
<video>MyVideoLOL</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will remove the video tags from around the tag value:

```
myVideoUrl:String = getVideoTagValue( '<video>someUrl.com</video>' );

function getVideoTagValue( tagString:String ):String
{
    tagString = tagString.replace( /(\<video\>)|(\<\/video\>)/ig, '' );

    return tagString;
}

trace(myVideoUrl);
```

The trace output in this case would be:  **someUrl.com**

You can then use that url in a video player.

Comment: Hmm i will try that, can you tell me how to also cut the ID of youtube vid? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RANDOMID , how can i get the randomid?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to derive the ID number from the RANDOMID variable.  That would be better asked as its own new question.  If my answer solves your original question, please checkmark my answer so the community knows its been solved.  Thanks!